# correlation between vectors of different lengths

Tags: matlab, correlation

How is it possible to find the correlation between vectors of different lengths? For example:

```
clear all 
time1 = 1 + (365-1).*rand(1,12);
time2 = 1 + (365-1).*rand(1,24);

data1 = 1 + (20-1).*rand(1,12);
data2 = 1 + (20-1).*rand(1,24);
```

usually I would find the correlation with:

```
R = corrcoef(data1,data2);
```

but the vectors need to be the same lengths! How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your vectors are signals sampled at different frequencies as you stated above in a comment, and if for both of the signals you are above the Nyquist Rate, you can upsample/downsample hence interpolate/decimate the discrete time signal without losing any information. Then you can use the standard correlation measure.

Answer (score 3):

A) You take (or copy) the longer vector, remove all data points that have no equivalent in the shorter one, then calculate correlation as usual.

B) You define your own measure of "correlation between vectors of different lengths" and what this is supposed to measure in the first place, then calculate it. (Do not hesitate to post your results here. I suppose it will be innovative.)

Comment: A) But, if both vectors are time series and the measurements are not taken at the same periods, you cannot simply remove the data points which are not similar to the shorter vector.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly correlation but you can find similarity between two signals of unequal lengths using Dynamic Time Warping.
DTW optimises temporal alignment based on certain rules and does 1-to-many mappings between datapoints instead of the conventional 1-to-1, which allows for a better match (with reduced total euclidean distance) between the two signals.